# React project: Unity or three.js?

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, three.js, frontend, webgl

Recently, the React project plans to adopt a 3D map, which will be a complex scene. It will be a city with different plots, beaches, mountains, and interaction. You can choose, click and drag, etc.

The team currently has three.js (I can do a little), Unity (no one can).

So it's a question of using three.js or Unity?

If I choose three.js, I will study hard and develop while doing; Assuming unity is selected, a Unity developer will be hired to interact with the project using React-Unity-webGL.

I don't know if there's a better plan

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably too opinion based to avoid being closed, but I wanted to let you know that Three.js very much has the ability to handle robust animations and interactions.

Proof of point, check out [Bruno Simon's portfolio page](https://bruno-simon.com/).

At that point, it comes down to whether you have the bandwidth to be researching so much as you work, or if you would prefer to hire someone who knows Three.js or Unity to a greater extent and can deliver more quickly.